# Java Sound API encodes my wav file wrong? (on macOS)

Tags: java, macos, audio, wav, java-11

I'm trying to record sound from my microphone and simply dump it into a wav file.

I have tried code from several tutorials. When I write the `AudioInputStream` to a wav file my program does create the wav file. When

When I look in the file browser it is the correct length of time, frame rate, and it does have a size (is not empty). But when I play the wav file, there is no sound, its blank.

I have verified that the `TargetDataLine` I'm using is indeed the built-in microphone. I have tried closing all other applications apart from the terminal to make sure nothing else might possibly have the microphone open as a resource, and I have tried packaging the program and running it from the default mac terminal, to make sure I had permission to access the resource.

I am on a macOS 12.3.1, using JavaSE 11.

I am fully prepared for this to be an issue with my computer or something, because the tutorial code I've been using seems to work for everyone else.

Here is my code:

```
    public class AudioVisualiser {

    TargetDataLine targetLine;

    public AudioVisualiser() {
        initialise();
    }

    public void initialise() {
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
        
        try {

            //Microphone
            TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format));
            targetLine.open();

            System.out.println(targetLine.available());

            Thread monitorThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    targetLine.start();
                    File outputFile = new File("recording.wav");

                    AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(targetLine);
                    int written = 0;
                    try {written = AudioSystem.write(stream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outputFile);}
                    catch (IOException e) {throw new Error("Problem writing to file");}
                    try {stream.close();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                    System.out.println("written bytes = "+written);
                }
            };


            System.out.println("Start Monitor");
            monitorThread.start();

            Thread.sleep(3000);

            System.out.println(targetLine.available());
            targetLine.stop();
            targetLine.close();
            System.out.println("End Monitor");

        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie) { ie.printStackTrace();}
        catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {System.out.println("Problem opening line");}

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AudioVisualiser();
    }
```

Here is a picture of the created wav file. It has a size, but it is just blank.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a couple recent threads (since 2020) pertaining to the issue of accessing the microphone on a Mac. But I can't tell if the issue was actually solved or not. The threads both suggest trying Java 17.0.2 or later.

[Request to Access Microphone](https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/222)

[How to Request Microphone Access](https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/281)

I have a Windows and a Linux computer, no Mac, so I am unable to test if the problem continues post 17.0.2.

Comment: Yo those look super promising, thanks so much for the links they articulate the exact problem I’m having.  Will have a look now, honestly cheers man